# Running a shell script in Windows AND MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, sh

I am trying to make a python3 script that is compatible with Windows and Mac OS. I've got the script working on Mac, and now I'm trying to make it work with Windows. It looks like I'm using system specific commands ('clear' and 'sh') that are causing some problems.

Here's the script:

```
import os

clear = lambda: os.system("clear")


while True:
    os.system("echo \U0001F525=-=-=-=-=-=-Main Menu=-=-=-=-=-=-\U0001F525")
    os.system("echo")
    choice = str(
        input(" 0. Press '0' to perform environment setup.\n 1. Press '1' to delete files.\n 2. Press '2' to exit.\n\n> ")
    )
    clear()
    if choice == "0":
        os.system("sh config.sh")
    elif choice == "1":
        os.system("echo Entering delete files mode")
    elif choice == "2":
        exit()
```

And here are the errors I'm getting when trying to run this file on windows:

```
'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

ECHO is on.
```

Here's the shell script I'm trying to run in `config.sh`

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Lastly, here's my requirements.txt file

```
flask
```

Comment: Edit the question to show what you have tried already.

Comment: `clear` on windows is `cls` (dumb, I know). For a windows shell script, use a file with a `.bat` extension and call `os.system('C:\Path\to\batfile.bat')`

Comment: You can set a flag to True/False depending on the host operating system and then use the appropriate commands and `sh` vs `bat` files for it. Look into the Python `platform` module.

Comment: Why are you using `os.system` to run `echo`? Python has a `print` function.